# Symfony2 Apc "Cannot redeclare...."

Tags: php, symfony, apc

please, can you help me with using symfony2 apc class loader? I´m trying to set it up but it throws me error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2576

Here is my app.php file: http://pastebin.com/b3iE6cWq

I used this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/cache_class_loader.html

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: did u clear cache?   php app/console cache:clear

Comment: So do you have any idea what to do with it?